# Multiple swagger instances for a single application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to host public and internal APIs on swagger UI and want to separate them out into different URLs like:-

1. /public/swagger-ui.html
2. /internal/swagger-ui.html

Currently, all my APIs are placed under /swagger-ui.html.
Is there a way how I can achieve it using spring boot?

Comment: can https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/213 or https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3693 help you?